# How to tell rebar3 to run tests in dependencies

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I want my rebar3 application to test itself and all of its dependencies. Is it possible in rebar3?
I've created a simple 'test' plugin that tries to execute `rebar_prv_eunit:do/1` over all applications in the project and their dependencies but it doesn't work.

Here's the code for it https://github.com/kubaodias/rebar3-test-plugin

Comment: What's wrong with [`rebar3 eunit`](https://www.rebar3.org/v3/docs/running-tests)?

Comment: It tests only the current application. I'd also like to test all of its dependencies from rebar.config.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
ls -d */ | xargs -I {} bash -c "cd {} ; rebar3 eunit; cd -"
```

This cmd will traverse and run eunit in the folders.